# How do I create a method to calculate a commission fee in Java

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a method in Java where a band has a commissioning fee based on the number of artists it has. So it will be 10 pounds for each artist.On the program, when you create the band, you input the artists in the band. The commission fee is then based on the number of artists ( £40 for each artist).

What I currently have is:

```
private void setCommission()
{
    commission = artists+40;
}
```

Can someone advise on how I can get my method to function correctly or if theres anything else I should add to my current version.

Comment: By working out how to calculate a commission fee, then implementing that solution as Java code. :)

Comment: You need to provide more code than that. It might be as simple as `artists.size()*40` (notice `*` not `+`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void setCommission() {
    commission = (artists * 40);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your math is messed up. It should be `artists * 40` Or, if artists is a list of some sort than you need to multiply its length by 40.

Comment: Note that this is only if `artists` is the amount of artists, not a list or array of them. If it's the latter, it should be something like `artists.length * 40` or `artists.size() * 40`.

Comment: Didnt have my thinking cap on, monday morning blues I guess. Thanks for the help. And no, currently artists isnt a list or array. It will just be defined in the constructor.